# How can do Scrollable View and this get the position?

Tags: android, scroll, scrollview

How can do a scrollable view, and this gets the position in the view and change the placeholder . The information in the view must be charged from the DataBase and it must change with the time.

[image: scrollable view]

How can do the placeholder?

can i do that the Placeholder change if i use a horizontalscrollview , and the placeholder be independent ?

another idea to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is exactly what you want. A viewpager indicator. Check it out - 
[Jack Wharton's View Pager Indicator library](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into the new ViewPager from the support package. It's made to do this sort of thing..

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html